# How to create an ipc communication win-form within a project

Tags: c#, winforms, ipc

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
 {
   private Process subProcess;
   Counter counter = new Counter();
   public Form1(string[] args)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        if (args.Length == 0 || args[0].IndexOf("-subMonitor") == -1)
        {
            IpcServerChannel serverChannel = new IpcServerChannel("serverchannel");

            RemotingConfiguration.RegisterWellKnownServiceType(typeof(Counter), "counter", WellKnownObjectMode.Singleton);
            Console.WriteLine("This is call number " + counter.Count); 
            Console.WriteLine("This is call number " + counter.Count);
            Console.WriteLine("Listening on " + serverChannel.GetChannelUri());

            // MainProcess
            subProcess = new Process();

            subProcess.StartInfo.FileName = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;
            subProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = "-subMonitor";
            subProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;

            subProcess.Start();

            Button btn = new Button();
            btn.Size = new Size(100, 100);
            btn.Location = new Point(0, 0);
            this.Controls.Add(btn);
            btn.BringToFront();

            btn.MouseUp += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(btnMouseUp);
        }
        else
        {

            Button btn = new Button();
            btn.Size = new Size(100, 100);
            btn.Location = new Point(0, 0);
            this.Controls.Add(btn);
            btn.BringToFront();

            btn.MouseUp += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(btnMouseUp);
            // SubProcess
            //Console.WriteLine(args[0]);

            IpcClientChannel clientChannel = new IpcClientChannel();
            RemotingConfiguration.RegisterWellKnownClientType(typeof(Counter), "ipc://serverchannel/counter");

        }

    }

    private void btnMouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(counter.Count.ToString());
    }
}



public class Counter : MarshalByRefObject
{

    private static int count = 0;
    public int Count
    {
        get
        {
            return (count++);
        }
    }
}
```

I want to communicate with same program by ipc.
The same subprocess is opened when the process is executed.

for testing, I made a valuable, Counter that is Singleton Object.
I want to be shared a singleton object called Count.
but It is not working.

I want a result.....

If I click a Main btn button, this result is
2,3,4,5
If I click a Sub btn button, this result is
6,7,8

but this result is....

If I click a Main btn button, this result is
2,3,4,5
If I click a Sub btn button, this result is
0,1,2...

It is not Singleton Object.

What is wrong with it?

Comment: paste code of IpcServerChannel

Comment: To use .NET Remoting is a bad idea. It became obsolete years ago, even for desktop apps. Maybe, there still exist some dinosaurs, who knows, how to use it, but it's better to use something else. Since you're writing Windows desktop app, WCF will be good choice (albeit it's rather old too). Type "c# wcf ipc" in brower's search box - there are tons of code samples.

Comment: @Timeless: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Runtime.Remoting/channels/ipc/ipcserverchannel.cs